# Passing string to javascript function parameter gets parsed as integer

Tags: javascript, php

There are tons of questions on passing strings to a javascript function - that's not what I'm asking here. My problem is that I have to pass an integer (a customer ID) as a string to a javascript function from PHP. The reason I have to do this is sometimes a customer ID can have leading zeros, and I do not know how many leading zeros will be needed, so I can't pad or format with leading zeros in javascript.

Here's the PHP that calls my function. The $row is a resulting array from an odbc query.

```
parse_str("customerId=" . $row["customerId"], $output);
// This is called via AJAX, so returning HTML as response
...
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='" . $output["customerId"] . "' onclick='disableAccount(" . $row["userAccountId"] . ", " . $output["customerId"] . ");' checked /></td>
```

The above works fine, and correctly passes a string with leading zeros to the funtion. Here's part of that function.

```
function disableAccount(userAccountId, customerId) {
// Do stuff here
}
```

As an example, I have a customerId of "026608". When the `disableAccount` function is called, the `customerId` parameter is parsed as an integer, which strips the leading zero, and I now have a parameter of '26608'.

As I mentioned above, I can't use padding to add a leading zero to the customerId, as there isn't always a leading zero on the customerId. The customerId can also have more than one leading zero.

How can I get my function to parse a string, i.e. "026608" as a parameter with the leading zeros? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it has leading zeros it's not an integer, it's a string. If you need it to process with leading zeroes, send it as a string the entire way.

Comment: Your php is not wrapping that value in quotes as it writes out the params to the onclick handler, so it will be a number.

Comment: "The above works fine, and correctly passes a string with leading zeros to the funtion." No it doesn't.

Comment: What database are you using Riccaforte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to pass/escape the quotes so it gets parsed as string by the js

```
(\"" . $row["userAccountId"] . \""
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I thought it was being passed correctly, because I'm also using this value to set the element's ID in a while loop. Since the ID was coming in correctly there, I thought it was being passed correctly to the function.

Comment: you´re welcome, glad it helped ;) this way your js-function is called `disableAccount("026608"...` instead of `disableAccount(026608...`

Answer (score 1):

Great spot by john Smith, also another useful function for leading zeroes (though in this instance, not more efficient than john's) is the [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function.

```
$id = 321;

function disableAccount($userAccountId, customerId)
    {
    //Result is 000321
    $userAccIdWithZeros = sprintf('%06d', $userAccountId);

    //Rest of your code...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax whenever you produce HTML in PHP, it's more readable:

```
echo <<< _
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" 
           id="{$output['customerId']}" 
           onclick="disableAccount('{$row['userAccountId']}', this.id);" 
           checked />
</td>
_;
```

... because you don't have to escape your quotes, and you might have spotted your issue at once.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about that!